# canvas does not draw image on load

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I started to play with canvas coding and I'm stuck on a (most likely) very easy issue. I have a code which on click lads some image, and I would like to put the image on canvas when it's loaded. When I go to diagnostic tools in Chrome, the pictures get loaded and there is no errors in the console, yet the images do get drawn on the canvas.

any ideas why?

```
    sAlphaF = new Image();
    sAlphaF.src = '/img/sAlpha_'+tbaID+'_f.png';
    sAlphaF.onload = function(){
        var ctxs=gc.getContext("2d");
        ctxs.drawImage(sAlphaF,0,0, gc.width, gc.length);
    };
    tAlphaF = new Image();
    tAlphaF.src = '/img/tAlpha_'+tbaID+'_f.png';
    tAlphaF.onload = function(){
        var ctxt=bc.getContext("2d");
        ctxt.drawImage(tAlphaF,0,0, bc.width, bc.length);
    };
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: are bc.width and bc.length valid?

Comment: are you sure you should use bc.length isntead of bc.height?

Comment: ahh silly me... it's bc.height, not length.. going to check

Comment: works -.- cheers, if you make it an answer, I will approve ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `bc.length` property to `bc.height` ;)